# Spooling in sqlplus for Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have .sql file with 100s of Oracle queries, so while spooling the results of all 100s queries are getting written into one file, but I want a single file should be created for every single query, for 100 queries there should be 100 files having result for their particular query.

Comment: You will have to put something before each query, whether it's an explicit `spool` command or a call to a script. How should the output files be named? Sequential numbers, timestamp, GUID, something else? Also, should this be for SQL*Plus specifically, in which case why the `oracle-sqldeveloper` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it obvious? Set SPOOL before SELECT and SPOOL OFF after it. That's a lot of typing as every SPOOL should have its own file name.

Perhaps you could create a script which would do that for you. Using UTL_FILE, you'd read line-by-line and create *generic* spool file name (such as Q1.TXT, Q2.TXT, ...), writing everything back into a new large SQL file.

Here's an example. My LARGE.SQL contains several SELECT statements:

```
select count(*) from tab;

select department_name from departments
where department_id < 100;

select sysdate 
from dual;
```

The following script creates a LARGE_W.SQL which has SPOOL commands inserted between every SELECT:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_file_r utl_file.file_type;  -- read large.sql
  3    l_file_w utl_file.file_type;  -- write large_2.sql
  4    l_text   varchar2(32767);     -- read line by line
  5    i        number := 1;         -- counter
  6  begin
  7    l_file_r := utl_file.fopen('EXT_DIR', 'large.sql'  , 'r');
  8    l_file_w := utl_file.fopen('EXT_DIR', 'large_w.sql', 'w');
  9
 10    begin
 11      loop
 12        utl_file.get_line(l_file_r, l_text, 32767);
 13
 14        if regexp_substr(trim(upper(l_text)), '^\w+') = 'SELECT' then
 15           -- the first word is SELECT
 16           utl_file.put_line(l_file_w, 'SPOOL OFF');
 17           utl_file.put_line(l_file_w, 'SPOOL Q' || to_char(i) ||'.TXT');
 18           i := i + 1;
 19        end if;
 20        -- lines different than 1st in this SELECT section
 21        utl_file.put_line(l_file_w, l_text);
 22      end loop;
 23    exception
 24      when no_data_found then
 25        utl_file.put_line(l_file_w, 'SPOOL OFF');
 26        null;
 27    end;
 28
 29    utl_file.fclose(l_file_r);
 30    utl_file.fclose(l_file_w);
 31  end;
 32  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

The result is LARGE_W.SQL

```
SPOOL OFF
SPOOL Q1.TXT
select count(*) from tab;

SPOOL OFF
SPOOL Q2.TXT
select department_name from departments
where department_id < 100;

SPOOL OFF
SPOOL Q3.TXT
select sysdate 
from dual;
SPOOL OFF
```

When ran, it creates 3 Qn.TXT files:

```
SQL> @c:\temp\large_w.sql
not spooling currently

  COUNT(*)
----------
        40


DEPARTMENT_NAME
------------------------------
Administration
Marketing
Purchasing
Human Resources
Shipping
IT
Public Relations
Sales
Executive

9 rows selected.


SYSDATE
--------
16:09:42

SQL> $dir q*.txt
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 7635-F892

 Directory of C:\Users\lf

21.01.2018.  16:09               250 Q1.TXT
21.01.2018.  16:09               926 Q2.TXT
21.01.2018.  16:09               250 Q3.TXT
               3 File(s)          1.426 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  351.802.810.368 bytes free

SQL> $type q1.txt

  COUNT(*)
----------
        40


SQL>
```

That's just an idea; of course, it might need improvement (hint: subqueries), but now you've got something to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running sqlplus in UNIX environment, you might convert every semicolon into a spool command with unique output file using an awk command like this. The last one is extra, which you may eliminate (or modify `awk` !)

```
awk '{gsub(";",";\nspool outputfile_"NR,$0);print}' yoursqlfile.sql >newsqlfile.sql
```

This would convert a file such as

```
spool file1
select 1 FROM DUAL;
select 2 FROM DUAL;
select 3 FROM
(select 4 FROM DUAL);
SELECT 5 FROM
DUAL;
```

*TO*

```
spool file1
select 1 FROM DUAL;
spool outputfile_2
select 2 FROM DUAL;
spool outputfile_3
select 3 FROM
(select 4 FROM DUAL);
spool outputfile_5
SELECT 5 FROM
DUAL;
spool outputfile_7
```